# Get maxSatisfying version including pre-release with node semver

Tags: node.js, semantic-versioning

How can i get the latest version (including the pre-releases) from an array of versions using node/semver.

For example:

```
var semver = require("semver");
var versions = ["1.0.0-rc.10","1.0.0-rc.11"];
console.log(semver.maxSatisfying(versions, "*"));
```

Returns null, but i want to get the 1.0.0-rc.11 back.

Kind Regards and have a nice day!

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the `includePrerelease` option to your `maxSatisfying` method as described here: https://github.com/npm/node-semver#functions

In your example:

```
var semver = require("semver");
var versions = ["1.0.0-rc.10","1.0.0-rc.11"];

console.log(semver.maxSatisfying(versions, "*", {
        includePrerelease: true
}));
```

Comment: Almost 5 years past)

Comment: Yet can be helpful for other peoples

Answer (score 1):

Okay i've found a solution.

The node module `semver-extra` adds some nice extra functions to the semver library, also one for getting the max version including the pre-releases.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver-extra